# Couldn't find `document._registerDartTypeUpgrader`

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

My previously executing application now fails to run with the following stacktrace

`Exception: Unsupported operation: Couldn't find 'document._registerDartTypeUpgrader'. Please make sure that 'packages/web_components/interop_support.html' is loaded and available before calling this function. (package:web_components/interop.dart:24)`

What exactly does this means.

Comment: I have never seen this message before. Have you tried `pub upgrade`, `pub cache repair`?

Comment: No. In what directory do I run these commands?

Comment: In the directory of your package where the `pubspec.yaml` file is.

Comment: I have run the commands above but the output is still the same.

Comment: Do you have the polymer transformer configuration with the entry_points in your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Yes and     
    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script> is included in the entry_point.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but only on my Windows machine. On my MacBook it works OK with the exact same code.

UPDATE:

I've compared my Windows machine with the MacBook regarding versions. They both have:

- DartSDK 1.7.2_r41096
- Chromium 37.0.2062.120 (292122)
- The packges folder symlinks point to the exact same version folder for every package

Still no idea what the difference is.

UPDATE:

Got it working after changing version to "any" for some packages and doing a "pub upgrade". I checked in the pubspec.lock which packages were upgraded. If you depend on any of these it might help if you upgrade them:

- args
- barback
- code_transformers
- collection
- core_elements intl
- paper_elements
- smoke source_maps
- stack_trace
- string_scanner

In particular I suspect the old version of core_elements and paper_elements to have caused the problem but I have not reproduced it.